# Porque Retorna NaN? e como retornar Number?

Tags: javascript

Porque o seguinte código retorna NaN (Not a Number)? - e como retornar o resultado de (saldo) * (índice) em number?

```js
function ContaPoupanca(){
            this.saldo = 0;
            this.deposita = function(valor){
                this.saldo += valor;
            };
            this.atualiza = function(indice){
                this.saldo += this.saldo * this.indice;
            };
        };
var contaPoupanca = new ContaPoupanca();
contaPoupanca.deposita(1000);
console.log(contaPoupanca.saldo);
contaPoupanca.atualiza(0.05);
console.log(contaPoupanca.saldo);
```

Comment: Troca de  this.indice para indice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro está em `this.indice`. Você está tentando acessar uma propriedade do seu objeto `ContaPoupanca` que não existe, ao invés de acessar o parâmetro da função. O correto nesse caso é apenas `indice`. Veja:

```js
function ContaPoupanca(){
            this.saldo = 0;
            this.deposita = function(valor){
                this.saldo += valor;
            };
            this.atualiza = function(indice){
                this.saldo += this.saldo * indice;
            };
        };
var contaPoupanca = new ContaPoupanca();
contaPoupanca.deposita(1000);
console.log(contaPoupanca.saldo);
contaPoupanca.atualiza(0.05);
console.log(contaPoupanca.saldo);
```